# Use (libccd) shared library for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cmake, shared-libraries, collision-detection

I want to do collision detection in MATLAB. In MATLAB its possible to include a shared library written in C with

```
loadlibrary();
```

I found a collision detection library written in C:

https://github.com/danfis/libccd

The documentary says that

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
make && make install
```

build libccd as a shared library. After execute these commands in terminal I get a libccd.dylib. Thats what I need for MATLAB...

```
loadlibrary('libccd');
```

But MATLAB wants a header file (or more than one) in addition to the shared library.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html

So I added the ccd.h file to the loadlibrary command. Then the problem is that ccd.h includes another header file but in an under folder: ccd/vec3.h
It seems that MATLAB has a problem with this.

So my questions are:

1. I don't know if the ccd.h file is the correct file to link first. Which one should I use?
2. How to resolve the problem that MATLAB can not find a file in another path
3. I don't know what

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
make && make install
```

does. Maybe I should build a shared library my own. But I am not a programmer and never worked with Cmake, Makefiles and so on.

Thanks for every help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `'addheader'`option to `loadlibrary`.

```matlab
loadlibrary('libccd', 'ccd.h', 'addheader', 'ccd/vec3')
```

Rinse and repeat for all the headers it needs.